# How do I solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation $$ f(f(-1)) = \sqrt{2} + g(f(2)), $$
where $$f(x) = \dfrac{a}{x^2} - 3x + 2, \quad g(x) = a\cdot \sin 2x$$
$a$ is unknown. The solution is $a \approx{-5.81}$. I tried

```
Clear[f];
Clear[g];
f[x_] := a/x^2 - 3 x + 2;
g[x_] := a*Sin[2 x];
Solve[f[f[-1]] == Sqrt[2] + g[f[2]], a]
```

and

```
Clear[f];
Clear[g];
f[x_] := a/x^2 - 3 x + 2;
g[x_] := a*Sin[2 x];
Reduce[f[f[-1]] == Sqrt[2] + g[f[2]], a]
```

but, I got the following error:

> "Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved which the methods available to Reduce."

This is a picture of the desired solution that I drew in GeoGebra

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oftentimes, it is the case that `Solve` and `Reduce` cannot find a general solution in $\mathbb{C}$, but if you know *a priori* that your solution set is in $\mathbb{R}$, then you can call these functions with the domain specification and it will give you the solution (if solvable).

```
NSolve[f[f[-1]] == Sqrt[2] + g[f[2]], a, Reals]
(* {{a -> -5.81218}} *)
```

Here's how you can reproduce your GeoGebra plot:

```
With[{sol = a /. NSolve[f[f[-1]] == Sqrt[2] + g[f[2]], a, Reals] // First},
    Plot[{g@f@2, f@f@-1}, {a, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, 
        Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{sol, g@f@2 /. a -> sol}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry. I ask SOlVE many times, but I don't notice. I will try.

Comment: I repaired `f[x_] := a/x^2 - x + 2;` and I get NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

Comment: @minthao_2011 In that case, you have multiple (possibly infinite) solutions which don't have a general formula,  which is why `NSolve` doesn't return a solution. Restrict the range of `a` by adding a condition `&&amin ≤ a ≤ amax` and you'll get the solutions in that range

Answer (score 17):

First of all it is a good programming style is to use functions with their explicit (independent) variables, i.e. if one has to solve an equation with respect to a parameter, it should be treated as an **explicit argument**. Thus we define the functions this way :

```
f[x_, a_] := a/x^2 - 3 x + 2
g[x_, a_] := a Sin[2 x]
```

The question doesn't imply that the solution must be necessarily real. In fact, there is only one real solution, you can find it this way :

```
Solve[ f[ f[-1, a], a] == Sqrt[2] + g[ f[ 2, a], a], a, Reals]
```

but since there are (most likely infinitely) many complex solutions and since `Mathematica` is to find them all, we should tell the system to restrict somehow the search for solutions to a region where it may have only finite numbers of solutions. In order to provide a completion to algorithms behind equation-solving functionality we need to restrict the search for roots to a finite complex range (e.g. square - like ). For the sake of brevity we define a new function :

```
funcfg[a_] := f[ f[ -1, a], a] - Sqrt[2] - g[ f[ 2, a], a]
```

Let's find all roots of `funcfg` e.g. in a circle of radius `51` with the center in `0`, i.e. where complex numbers satisfy `Abs[a] < 51` :

```
sol = Solve[ funcfg[a] == 0 && Abs[a] < 51, a];
```

There are

```
Length @ sol
```

> ```
> 21
> ```

solutions, so write here only `3` of them, e.g. (from `8`-th to `10`-th) :

```
sol[[8 ;; 10, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {Root[{325 + 25 Sqrt[2] + 204 #1 + 10 Sqrt[2] #1 + 25 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1 + 43 #1^2
>        + Sqrt[2] #1^2 + 10 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^2 + 3 #1^3 + Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^3 &, 
>       -11.953414742816708318902832339138612161461271256190 + 
>         2.454413085381160585476672761493761068260205214286 I}], 
>  Root[{325 + 25 Sqrt[2] + 204 #1 + 10 Sqrt[2] #1 + 25 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1 + 43 #1^2 
>        + Sqrt[2] #1^2 + 10 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^2 + 3 #1^3 + Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^3 &,
>        -5.81217740175980465827061286458}], 
>  Root[{325 + 25 Sqrt[2] + 204 #1 + 10 Sqrt[2] #1 + 25 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1 + 43 #1^2
>        + Sqrt[2] #1^2 + 10 Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^2 + 3 #1^3 + Sin[2 (-4 + #1/4)] #1^3 &, 
>        - 4.131337899047017233724977013012392200221448674862
>        - 0.658093853165542882211799231745725310996904431942 I}]}
> ```

You can see there is that only one real near `-5.8121`.

```
roots = {Re @ #, Im @ #}& /@ sol[[All, 1, 2, 1, 2]];
```

Now we'd like to plot **only 3 roots** of the function in an especially more restricted region to to discover its **trefoil-quatrefoil like structure** :

```
GraphicsRow[
  Table[ Show[
    ContourPlot @@@ {
      { h[ funcfg[x + I y]], ##, Contours -> 11, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
        Epilog -> {PointSize[0.025], Red, Point[roots]}},
      { Re[ funcfg[x + I y]] == 0, ##, ContourStyle -> {Darker @ Green, Thick}},
      { Im[ funcfg[x + I y]] == 0, ##, ContourStyle -> {Cyan, Thick}}}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic], {h, {Re, Im}}]& @ Sequence[{x, -6, -3.8}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: nice colours...