# How can I find a root of my transcendental equation near a certain point?

Tags: equation-solving

What function could I use to solve this equation for x:

```
E^(-x^2) = 1 - Cos[x]
```

I tried `Solve`, `Reduce`, `Root`... None of them worked.

`FindInstance` gave me an imaginary answer.

Adding `Reals`, gave me:

```
{{x -> Root[{-1 + E^-#1^2 + Cos[#1] &, -6.28318531096301494721675292506}]}}
```

but this is not the answer I wanted, which would be between 0 and 1.

How would I solve this?

As a side note, [WolframAlpha got it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-x%5E2%29=1-cos%28x%29).

Comment: E.g. `Solve[E^(-x^2) == 1 - Cos[x] && 0 <= x <= 1, x]` yields `{{x -> Root[{1 - E^#1^2 + E^#1^2 Cos[#1] &, 0.94194408148019155746}]}}`.  See e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Comment: The reason `Solve` has a hard time is that it tries to find all solutions, but there are actually infinitely many of them: two each surrounding $x=2n\pi$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. (So WolframAlpha's answer is misleading.) Restricting the domain, as in Artes' comment, helps because then there are only a finite number of solutions.

Comment: Take a look also at [How do I solve this equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-do-i-solve-this-equation/16906#16906) and [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697).

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
NSolve[E^(-x^2) == 1 - Cos[x] && 0 < x < 1, x]
(* {{x -> 0.941944}} *)
```

Or this?

```
FindRoot[E^(-x^2) - (1 - Cos[x]), {x, 1}]
(* {x -> 0.941944} *)
```