# Closed solutions for `FindRoot`, no solutions for `Reduce` or `Solve`

Tags: equation-solving

`Reduce`, `Solve` and `FindRoot` all appear to struggle with this:

```
a[t_] := 1 + Cos[t] + Cos[2 t]
b[t_] := Sin[t] + Sin[2 t]
c[t_] := Sqrt[(Cos[t] + 2*Cos[2*t])^2 + (-Sin[t] - 2*Sin[2*t])^2]
d[t_] := Abs[-(Derivative[1][b][t]*Derivative[2][a][t]) + 
Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[2][b][t]]/(Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + 
Derivative[1][b][t]^2)^(3/2)
Solve[c[t] == 2/d[t], t]
FindRoot[c[t] == 2/d[t], {t, 2 Pi/3}]

(*out:
{}
{t -> 2.0944}
*)
```

Expected result is $2\pi/3$, the real roots being periodic:

[image]

but *Mathematica* appears to have difficulty with `Solve` and `Reduce` and it doesn't give a closed solution for the `FindRoot`. Is there anything I can do to yeild the expected result?

Comment: `Solve[c[t] == 2/d[t] && 0 < t < Pi, t]`. You should read [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697), these are also on topic [How do I solve this equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-do-i-solve-this-equation/16906#16906) and [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935)

Comment: @Artes thank you - I haven't seen any of these before - I will take a look now

Comment: @Artes thank you - `Reals` - silly me! BTW, what does `C[1]` mean?

Comment: This is a symbolic constant, don't use `C` symbol in Mathematica for your own variables. I recommend to read carefully all the above posts, then you will find adequate details concerning your problem.

Comment: @Artes, great - thank you for your help on this - will delete shortly.

Comment: Do as you wish but I guess it is crucial to read the posts before further actions.

Comment: @Artes OK will do. Do you know where I can find a ref to `C[1]` in the docs?

Comment: Highlight `C` and press `F1`.

Comment: @Artes brilliant! Thank you!